# Show progress in Windows Taskbar (Powershell)

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to figure out how to show progress on the taskbar. Via PowerShell.

[image]

As I understand it, I should use something like this:

```
$Progress = [System.Windows.Shell.TaskbarItemInfo]::New()

$Progress.ProgressState = 'Normal'
$Progress.ProgressValue = 0.3
```

But that does not work. What am I doing wrong? How to show progress on the taskbar? Thanks you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who are looking for an answer. As it turned out, the .NET Framework does not support show progress on the taskbar. Windows Forms also do not support this. It support on WPF now.

However, there is a solution. The solution was written by Ravikanth Chaganti. https://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/programming-windows-7-taskbar-using-windows-api-code-pack-and-powershell/. To do this, you need to download and install WindowsAPICodePack library (it was intended for Windows 7).:

Open PowerShell and load the assembly

`[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(“D:\API\Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.Dll”)`

Create a TaskBarManager instance

`$TaskBarObject = [Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.TaskBar.TaskBarManager]::Instance`

Set the ProgressBar state

`$TaskBarObject.SetProgressState(“Normal”)`

This is not mandatory. However, it is important to understand the possible values. Here is what each of the progress bar states mean:

No Progress – No progress bar is displayed
Indeterminate – The progress is indeterminate (marquee)
Normal – Normal progress is displayed
Error – An error occurred (red)
Paused – The operation is paused (yellow)

To set the progress bar value

`$TaskBarObject.SetProgressValue(50,100)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in WPF as using XAML creates a new window object, I don't think it's possible the way you're doing it.

```
# Add required assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration

# Setup the XAML
[xml]$script:xaml = '<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="MyWindow" Height="240" Width="320" Background="Gray">
 <Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
         <TaskbarItemInfo/>
 </Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
<Grid>
        <Image Name="image" Height="64" Width="64"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>'

# Create the form and set variables
$script:window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml))
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object { Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Script }



# This is the toolbar icon and description
$window.TaskbarItemInfo.Description = $window.Title
$window.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = 0.8
$window.TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = "Normal"


$window.ShowDialog()
```